# How to fix undefined error for document object in windows.onload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I am running any react app the following piece of error pops out.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at window.onload (content.js:5)
    window.onload   @   content.js:5
load (async)        
    (anonymous) @   content.js:1
```

Content in content.js is

```
window.onload=function()
{

    //Create an object for the frame
    var firstFrame = window.parent.frames[0].document;

    //Set JQuery events to run in the context of the frame
    $("#transliterateDiv", firstFrame).html("check");


    chrome.storage.local.get('typeNepaliContents', function(result){
        data = result;    
     });
}
```

The code doesn't disrupts the react workflow but still the error bothers me. What can be a quick fix for it?

Comment: do you have frames/iframes in window.parent? is window.parent same origin as window?

Comment: You can access a different frame's contents directly only if it's same-origin. Otherwise you need to make sure a content script is running on that URL, and use messaging to communicate.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes the windows.parent is same origin as window. Yes, The window object has a frame object as shown in the console.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I didn't get you. Would you elaborate ?

Comment: Without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) we can only guess, and while this is mildly fascinating, it's not the proper approach to solving problems. My guess this is a timing issue. How and when is that frame created exactly and why do you even need to access a parent window? Do you run content.js in an iframe that has chrome-extension:// URL?

Comment: and, you're serving all the html etc using a http server, you're not using `file:///` protocol?